# Material UI Icon cannot be found in '@mui/icons-material/Send.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Material UI library and I'm trying to import `SendIcon` by using the import statement:

```
import { SendIcon } from "@mui/icons-material/Send.js";
```

I have to include the `.js` extension because I included `"type" : "module"` in my `package.json` file.

However I'm getting the error:

```
export 'SendIcon' (imported as 'SendIcon') was not found in '@mui/icons-material/Send.js' (possible exports: __esModule, default)
```

I had installed all the necessary modules for Material UI but I'm not sure why this error is coming up?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check the documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons ? It shows how to import the icon when you click on it. Here it shows that SendIcon is exported as default. import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';  Without brackets {}

Comment: I removed the ```"type":"module"``` from my package.json and it works now. Is there a way to make it work with ```"type":"module"``` in the package.json file?

Comment: Did you try to import it as default, like I mentioned above? import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send.js';

Comment: Yes, but I got an error: ```React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.```

Comment: it looks like a bug in @mui, see https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/35233

default-imports do not work with ESM

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
import { SendIcon } from "@mui/icons-material/Send.js";
```

Try:

```
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
```

You can also search through the [Material Icon Page Search for 'Send'](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=send&selected=Send) to verify how to appropriately import a component.

Answer (score 0):

The icon import should be done using the following corrected format:

Incorrect way:

```js
import { SendIcon } from "@mui/icons-material/Send.js";
```

Correct way (using module import):

```js
import { SendIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";
```

Alternatively, you can use a named import like this:

```js
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
```

Both of these options will correctly import the SendIcon from the `"@mui/icons-material"` library.